# SAS, calculate row difference

Tags: sas, row, difference

```
data test;
input ID month d_month;
datalines;
1 59 0 
1 70 11
1 80 21
2 10 0 
2 11 1
2 13 3
3 5  0
3 9  4
4 8  0
;
run;
```

I have two columns of data ID and Month. Column 1 is the ID, the same ID may have multiple rows (1-5). The second column is the enrolled month. I want to create the third column. It calculates the different between the current month and the initial month for each ID.

Comment: Did you try using the `first.` function?

Comment: By initial month, you mean the very first month? So you mean the first time I see `ID`, that's the initial month? And current being the last observation of the same `ID`?

Comment: Please make sure to include anything you've tried as well as your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like that.

```
data test;
input ID month d_month;
datalines;
1 59 0 
1 70 11
1 80 21
2 10 0 
2 11 1
2 13 3
3 5  0
3 9  4
4 8  0
;
run;

data calc;
    set test;
    by id;
    retain current_month;

    if first.id then do;
        current_month=month;
        calc_month=0;
    end;

    if ^first.id then do;
        calc_month = month - current_month ;
    end;
run;
```

Krs

Comment: The d_month doesn't match calc_month. The second value of calc_month should be 11 (70 - 59) instead of 48.

Comment: Replace `calc_month=` with `calc_month = month - current_month` in the second data step, then it will be correct.